# WTForms. Динамическое заполнение SelectField

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, wtforms

Использую Flask-WTForms + SQLAlchemy. Есть форма, в которой есть поле SelectField, choices должны подгружаться в зависимости от ситуации. 
Написал небольшой скрипт на JS, который получает данные с сервера и заполняет ими Select. Но при обработке формы вылазит ошибка "Not a valid choice". Насколько я понимаю, это происходит потому, что choices в SelectField задаются непосредственно на серверсайде, и при обнаружений различий между начальными choices, заданными на бэкэнде, и теми, что приходят от пользователя, форма не проходит валидацию. Есть ли какой-нибудь способ решить эту проблему? Прогуглил все, что только можно, нашел только решение с редактированием исходников WTForms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Раз никто так и не ответил, то отвечу сам. Пришлось делать костыль в виде UnsafeSelectField, в котором отключена валидация, и проверять корректность данных самому при отправлении формы. Конечно, можно было бы зашить валидацию прямо в филд, но это не очень хороший сценарий по некоторым причинам: сложности с повторным использованием для разных целей, связывание формы и приложения (так как для корректной валидации при использовании данных из БД необходимо делать запрос к БД из формы, что не есть хорошо).

```
class UnsafeSelectField(SelectField):
    def pre_validate(self, form):
        return True
```